# AutoQuery with ResponseDTO in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I have created an AutoQuery function in my API with the use of the following code.

```
[Route("/cars/search")]
public class SearchCars : QueryDb<Car, CarDto>,  IJoin<Car, Equipment, Colour, FuelType, Manufacturer>
{
    public List<int> EquipmentIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> ManufacturerIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> ColourIds { get; set; }
}
```

The CarDto looks like this

```
public class CarDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Equipment> Equipment { get; set; }

    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int ManufactorId { get; set; }

    public FuelType FuelType { get; set; }
    public int FuelTypeId { get; set; }

    public byte[] ProfileImage { get; set; }
}
```

I was wondering if there are any specific values the IJoin looks for, because when I try to use this I get "Could not infer relationship between Car and Equipment"

Car looks like this.

```
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FuelTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<Equipment> Equipment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<int> EquipmentIds { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] ProfileImage { get; set; }
```

Equipment looks like this.

```
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public EquipmentType EquipmentType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int EquipmentTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

I realise that there would require alot of magic knowing that EquipmentIds is a list of Ids that it should check for in the Equipment table, but since everything else with ServiceStack is magic, I am giving it a try.

NB I have shortened some of the models because they are long and contains lots of information which is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any joins in [AutoQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) need to follow [OrmLite's Reference Conventions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#reference-conventions).

Comment: I renamed EquipmentIds to EquipmentId and that part worked. However there are information from several tables, and I guess they should be joined separately, like this IJoin<Car, Equipment>, IJoin<Car, Colour>, IJoin<Car, FuelType> and not like I have done in this example?

Comment: @AtleKristiansen If they need to join to `Car` they need to be done separately, [multiple IJoins](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#joining-multiple-tables) are for joining to the tables preceding it.

Comment: Ideally it would like to join the result from the first join with the second one, and so on. I tried to do this with IJoin<IJoin<Car, Equipment>, Colour> and so one, but that did not work.

Comment: Just after writing that I realised that I don't need to join any tables, as I only require the Ids for filtering purposes..

Comment: However when I now try to specify Cars/Search?EquipmentId=1&format=json I get the following error message; "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '[1]' to data type int."

Comment: @AtleKristiansen Again, please open a new question with full source code + Exception details. Wasn't it `EquipementIds`?

Comment: yeah, sorry mb. Created a new question.